# Android: EditText Shape

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

I want a custom shape for my `EditText` that looks like this:
[image]

First one is not focused and not pressed
Second one in not focused and pressed
Third one is focused

I know how to make that border when it is focused or pressed.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="shape_not_pressed_not_focused" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="shape_pressed_not_focused" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="shape_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

But how can I change the hint? I want it to slide smoothly to the side when the EditText is focused. How is that possible? And how can I change the Color from gray to black when it is pressed and from black to yellow when it is focused?

Comment: Why not a material [inputtextfield](https://material.io/components/text-fields/)?

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: But that doesn't really fit in my layout. I would like it exactly as shown above, but I don't know how to make that. Do I need to create a custom widget?